# parsing google oauth response

Tags: spring-mvc, google-oauth

I am implementing SSO to goole Oauth .

the response call :

```
https://host/sgoogle/oauth_gocb_login#state=/profile&access_token=ya29.vACd-iHLxYjINnggCdiLoBPYFOFHbgvMVY54H56BZELygLulQcZdgNBo02SVnFFCpPUDgoHfVs_3vA&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

I have difficulties to find the right path :

```
    @RequestMapping("/oauth_gocb_login")
```

but it seems the right part is stripped.

```
    @RequestMapping("/oauth_gocb_login#state=/") don,t work .
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything after [# is not sent to server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). That particular response is meant to be accessed only by client (browser) side code. If you need it on the server side, you'll need to examine document.location.hash and submit a form with values in it to your server side.